# Silverlight Required AJAX,JQuery,Etc

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I have just started to learn Silverlight.

i have found that silverlight is used for developing WebApplication.

Now in generally WebApplication we are using AJAX,Jquery Etc. for performance issue.

suppose AJAX will submit only desired part of webpage to webserver.

now my question is,
does it required to use AJAX,JQUERY ete in SilverLight application

or it will automatically implemented in silverlight application?

Thanks.....

Answer (score 1):

you really don't need Ajax or Jquery in Silverlight Application, Microsoft Silverlight delivers a new generation of high-quality audio and video, engaging media experiences, and interactive applications for the Web.

In a way, Silverlight is much like Adobe's Flash in that it enables a bunch of functionality that "plain old HTML" simply doesn't support such as animation, video, multimedia and more. In fact, Silverlight is considered in many ways a Flash competitor.

watch it here : http://www.questpond.com/DemoVideos1/SilverLight/WhatisSilverLight/WhatisSilverLight.php

Comment: than how does silverlight submit only single textbox to a server? it will automatically done? as i generally using AJAX for that?

Comment: Read this links :- [1]http://allaboutasp.net/2009/04/silverlight-plug-in-lifecycle/
[2]http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=226
[3]http://stuff.seans.com/2009/03/23/hello-silverlight-world-part-3-the-lifecycle-of-a-silverlight-control/
[4]http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/32569.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You write your *whole* application in Silverlight and put a single Silverlight object onto the web page.

The application can be as simple or complex as you wish and the communication to the server and update of the UI is handled *inside* the application.

You don't need any JavaScript - unless your Silverlight needs to communicate with other HTML elements on the page.